# Task Scheduler is not running a task to the second

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

In Windows Task Scheduler, one of my tasks is scheduled to run at 4:14:58 PM, but it's running at 4:15:00 PM. To rule out any underlying problem, I scheduled the task to run at 4:17:00 PM, and it ran exactly at 4:17:00 PM. Does the Scheduler only run tasks to the minute and not to the second?

Comment: Natively I do not think you can set a single task to the second. Try this article and see if it helps.    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7769635/windows-task-scheduler-to-execute-tasks-in-seconds

Comment: Should I try third party scheduler tools then?

Comment: If you can find a third party scheduler, yes, try that.

Answer (score 0):

Normally schedule in normal/desktop/server (not realtime) OS work with increment of minute. Even you can see task scheduled for 10:00 to run in 10:00:01, 10:00:02, etc depend of the processes, system load, etc.

So consider change of operating system or reconsider scheduling it with preciseness of minute.

Comment: I had this problem with running a PING cmd process on a task, but I just created a new task and now Windows Task Scheduler is actually running to second. I'm not sure what fixed it.

Comment: @RajNarayanan, you should not rely on this (running task by scheduler) with second preciseness.